# Getting order Status in Virto commerce

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using Virto Commerce and trying to write an even listener, how do I get order Status

In ChageEntityEventLister.cs file, here :

```
public virtual void OnBeforeUpdate(T item, EntityEventArgs e)
{
     return;
}
```

How can I obtain the status of this EntityEventArgs element ?
I tried :

```
e.CurrentValues.ToString()
e.OriginalValues.GetValue("Status")
```

But it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

As an example you can check here

https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-community/blob/0238db63b60cda4708764e217439853bbc4fd184/src/Extensions/Client/CommerceWebClient/Services/Listeners/ReviewApprovedEventListener.cs

You can create a new listered like the sample below (it will be easier to maintain your code after we release new version):

```
using System.Linq;
using VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Frameworks.Email;
using VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Frameworks.Events;
using VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Frameworks.Extensions;
using VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Orders.Model;
using VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Orders.Repositories;
using VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Reviews.Model;
using VirtoCommerce.Web.Client.Services.Emails;

namespace VirtoCommerce.Web.Client.Services.Listeners
{

    public class OrderEventListener : ChangeEntityEventListener<Order>
    {
        private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;
        private readonly IEmailService _emailService;

        public OrderEventListener(IOrderRepository orderRepository, IEmailService emailService)
        {
            _orderRepository = orderRepository;
            _emailService = emailService;
        }

        public override void OnBeforeUpdate(Order order, EntityEventArgs e)
        {
            //Expand with line items in case they are not present in order object...
            order = _orderRepository.Orders.Expand("OrderForms.LineItems")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderGroupId == order.OrderGroupId);

            //Transition to Pending state
            if (e.CurrentValues.GetValue<int>("Status") == (int) OrderStatus.Pending
&& e.OriginalValues.GetValue<int>("Status") != (int)OrderStatus.Pending)
            {
                var message = new EmailMessage("name@youremail.com", "Hello pending test message succeed", true)
                {
                    From = "info@youremail.com",
                    Subject = "test"
                };
                _emailService.SendEmail(message);

            }
        }
    }
}
```